# How to Run FluentValidation Before Authorization Filter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, filter, authorization, dto, fluentvalidation

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project where I'm using FluentValidation for DTO validation and have also implemented custom authorization filters. Currently, I'm facing a challenge where the authorization filters are executed before FluentValidation checks, but I need FluentValidation to run first. This is important because I want to avoid unnecessary database hits that happen in my authorization filters if the incoming DTOs are invalid.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

Custom Authorization Filter: I have a custom authorization filter that checks user permissions. It accesses the database to validate permissions, so I want to avoid running this filter if the DTO is already invalid.

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Authorization logic that hits the database
    }
}
```

Controller Action: In my controller action, I use both the FluentValidation and the authorization filter.

```
[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyAuthorizationFilter))]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] MyDto myDto)
{
    // Controller action logic
}
```

My question is: How can I configure my ASP.NET Core application so that FluentValidation runs and completes before the execution of my custom authorization filter? I want to ensure that if a DTO is invalid per FluentValidation rules, the request should be terminated before reaching the authorization logic, thus avoiding unnecessary database operations.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is make an ActionFilter like the Authorization Filter you made

```
public class FluentValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //handle your fluent validation here and if it is fine
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        //else return error status code or throw exception
    }
}
```

Add this attribute in the previous line before the `[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyAuthorizationFilter))]` as `[FluentValidationAttribute]`

This will first check the validation and then go to db for auth.